# How to fix Error: fractional component exceeds decimals?

Tags: ethers.js, javascript, react

I cannot seem to be able to fix the error "`Error: fractional component exceeds decimals [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-NUMERIC_FAULT ] (fault="underflow", operation="parseFixed", code=NUMERIC_FAULT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)`"

My code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchHistory() {
      const ethersProvider = await alchemy.config.getProvider();
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, ABI, ethersProvider);
      const price = await contract.getPrice();
      const formatPrice = ethers.utils.formatEther(price);
      const increment = 0.00001;
      let priceIndex = ((formatPrice - increment*2).toFixed(5));
      const fetchedMessages = [];

      while (priceIndex >= 0) {
        const message = await contract.getMessages(ethers.utils.parseUnits((priceIndex.toString())));
        fetchedMessages.push(message);
        priceIndex -= increment;
      }

      setMessages(fetchedMessages);

      const newMessage = await contract.readMessage();
      setMessage(newMessage);
    }

    fetchHistory();
  }, []);
```

This line brings about the error:

```
const message = await contract.getMessages(ethers.utils.parseUnits((priceIndex.toString())));
```

I solved it in the beginning with
`let priceIndex = ((formatPrice - increment*2).toFixed(5));`
but then I realized as the price grows it breaks the app sometimes because it rounds the numbers so toFixed is not a solution

EDIT:

I fixed my problem by converting all the numbers to Wei (from Ethers) and getting rid of all the parsing and formatting functions.